# how to uninstall plugins from Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse

I have installed too many plugins in my Eclipse IDE, It is taking too much time to start.
I want to uninstall unnecessary plugins.

[image: i dont need liferay, grails...]

Comment: Eclipse's architecture is based on laziness, meaning most plugins don't run at startup; a plugin will only be loaded when some part of it's functionality is actually invoked. There are a few exceptions that force themselves to run at startup, which user @his points out below.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Go to menu `Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details` (beginning with Eclipse Luna: `Help > Installation Details`). There you can uninstall. If you installed via the marketplace you can also uninstall there.

But if you just want to speed up the startup you can go to `Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown` and switch off unnecessary capabilities.

Comment: In my installation history the Uninstall option is grayed out for some items. For example, I select an entry EGit (any of the entries there are about 5) and the uninstall button is disabled for all of them. This is preventing me from installing the correct version of EGit.

Answer (score 0):

Some Eclipse plug-ins and extensions on Windows are removed via the Control Panel - Programs and Features process.